# Password validation while typing with NODEJS

Tags: javascript, validation, passwords

I'm  new at web development and I have seen a very usefull features I wanna do in my website.

I'm looking for how to display a dynamic message while the user is typing is password in order to validate it while he is typing. The goal is to let him know if there is something missing during the process.

At first glance I can do it in a easy way with javascript vanilla, but as I do not have access to the dom I do not know how to it.

Thank you for your help :)

Lamine.

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that anyone can understand your problem properly.

Comment: Thank you for your message. I do not have any code. I did not even start to do it cause I can not have access to the dom.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have JavaScript act in response to the user typing in their web browser then you need to use client-side JavaScript (typically registering an input event listener on the field they are typing into). This requires access to the DOM.

Node.js can't help here. The closest it can come to being involved is to be running a server-side program, but that can only be triggered by an HTTP request or websocket message (both of which would require client-side JS to send them if it is to be in response to typing).

Comment: Ok I see I will ommited then for now, if there are no solution. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

In React you can use useEffect hook to call side effects from the database with every keystroke + clean up function as follows.

```
const [inputValue,setInputValue] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  let timer = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(inputValue)
  })
  return() => {
    clearTimeout(timer)
    console.log("Cleanup")
  }
},[inputValue])
```